# Pandas df.merge unexpected sorting behavior

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I cannot distinguish why I am getting a different behavior for a simple merge on the index of both DFs. Based on the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#pandas.DataFrame.merge)
I expect the resulting dataframe to follow the right DF index.

Case 1

```
staff= pd.DataFrame([1,2,3],index=['Kelly','Sally','James'])
student= pd.DataFrame(['Texas','Califa','South Dakota'],index=['James','Mike','Sally'])
pd.merge(student,staff,left_index=True,right_index=True,how='right')
```

I get:

```
        0_x             0_y
Kelly   NaN             22
Sally   South Dakota    38
James   Texas           45
```

which follows the right DF (staff) index

Case 2

```
left = pd.DataFrame(   { "A": ["A0", "A1", "A2", "A3"], "B": ["B0", "B1", "B2", "B3"]},
                                 index = ["K0", "K1", "K0", "K3"])
right = pd.DataFrame({"C": ["C0", "C1"], "D": ["D0", "D1"]}, index=["K1", "K0"])
pd.merge(left,right,left_index=True,right_index=True,how='right')
```

I get

```
     A  B   C   D
K0  A0  B0  C1  D1
K0  A2  B2  C1  D1
K1  A1  B1  C0  D0
```

BUT, I was expecting:

```
     A  B   C   D
K1  A1  B1  C0  D0
K0  A0  B0  C1  D1
K0  A2  B2  C1  D1
```

as in Case 1

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the duplicate values in the index which requires some overhead to positionally distinguish rows with the same index. This process will occur regardless of type of `merge`. Note [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) will also exhibit the same behaviour.

To workaround can [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), then join on the *column* `"index"` on both frames then [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) on the merged frame to return the `"index"` *column* to the index of the DataFrame.

```
merged = pd.merge(
    left.reset_index(),  # Create Index Column on left
    right.reset_index(),  # Create Index Column on right
    on='index', how='right'
).set_index('index').rename_axis(None)  # Put index back
```

`merged`:

```
     A   B   C   D
K1  A1  B1  C0  D0
K0  A0  B0  C1  D1
K0  A2  B2  C1  D1
```

---

Why does Case 1 work? The part of the alignment process that is causing the "unexpected" behaviour is the phase which uses positional ordering to distinguish different rows with the same index.

Notice what happens if we add a duplicate index value to the first example. Duplicate entries in a merge column require special care.

```
staff = pd.DataFrame([1, 2, 3], index=['Sally', 'Sally', 'James'])
student = pd.DataFrame(['Texas', 'Califa', 'South Dakota'],
                       index=['James', 'Mike', 'Sally'])
```

`staff`:

```
       0
Sally  1  # Kelly Changed to Sally
Sally  2 
James  3
```

Now `merge` produces:

```
merged = pd.merge(student, staff, left_index=True, right_index=True,
                  how='right')
```

`merged`:

```
                0_x  0_y
James         Texas    3
Sally  South Dakota    1  # Sally is now grouped and sorted last
Sally  South Dakota    2
```

Why? Well, when accessing the index at location "Sally" which Sally do we mean? And which value should be merged? This question is solved by sorting and grouping values so they appear in order and "Sally (1)" and "Sally (2)" can be distinguished as separate rows.

Again this process does not occur when the index values are unique (as there is no need to positionally identify rows as they are already uniquely identified).

---

Why does the workaround work? Well the *column* value "Sally" at index 0 and the *column* value "Sally" and index 1 are uniquely identified.

Comment: Why isn't the index alignment happening on Case 1 though?

Comment: The alignment does occur. It's actually the "group keys" portion of alignment that is causing the issue. take a look at my update

Comment: Henry, everything clicks now with your updated comment. I am curious though how do you know that? Is it by reading the source code or from experience with the same problem? The user guide does not cover this behavior explicitly. I am trying to learn more about what happens under the hood with Pandas. Thanks.

Comment: Both? I've read through a fair bit of the source code. But also from experience. In this case it was the source code. Merge with these non unique indexes will eventually get to [_join_non_unique](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/indexes/base.py#L4207). You may notice [get_join_indexers](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/indexes/base.py#L4218) has `sort=True` regardless of how the sort was set in the initial merge. You'll end up with `left_index [0, 2, 1]` and right index `[1, 1, 0]`.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html pd.merge has option to pass sort in the argument , which sort the join key as in yours is index.

```
staff= pd.DataFrame([1,2,3],index=['Kelly','Sally','James'])
student= pd.DataFrame(['Texas','Califa','South Dakota'],index= 
['James','Mike','Sally'])
pd.merge(student,staff,left_index=True,right_index=True,how='right', sort=True) 



        0_x    0_y
James   Texas   3
Kelly   NaN     1
Sally   South Dakota    2
```

you can also used sort index

```
left = pd.DataFrame(   { "A": ["A0", "A1", "A2", "A3"], "B": ["B0", "B1", "B2", "B3"]},
                             index = ["K0", "K1", "K0", "K3"])
right = pd.DataFrame({"C": ["C0", "C1"], "D": ["D0", "D1"]}, index=["K1", "K0"])
pd.merge(left,right,left_index=True,right_index=True,how='right').sort_index(ascending=True)

        A   B   C   D
  K1    A1  B1  C0  D0
  K0    A0  B0  C1  D1
  K0    A2  B2  C1  D1
```